# Как в java передать метод в качестве параметра

Tags: java, методы, параметры

Есть несколько методов, которые считают число согласных в слове по заданному параметру. Методы отличаются только типом принимаемого аргумента:

```
public int countPhonotype(Consonant.Place place) {
        int count = 0;
        for(Consonant cons : this.transcription) {
            if (cons.getPlace().equals(place)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

public int countPhonotype(Consonant.Manner manner) {
        int count = 0;
        for(Consonant cons : this.transcription) {
            if (cons.getManner().equals(manner)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Я хотел бы вынести общую часть в отдельный метод, но не могу найти решение, как передать туда метод. Пытался разобраться со ссылками на методы, но рабочий вариант не удался. Буду благодарен за помощь.

PS: методов в действительности гораздо больше двух, так что "оставлять как есть" не хотелось бы.

Comment: Через оператор ссылку например `Class::method`, через функциональные интерфейсы, через класс `Method`, через класс `Callable` или через `Lambda Expressions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно можно сделать

```java
private int countPhonotypeBy(Predicate<Consonant> p) {
    int count = 0;
    for(Consonant cons : this.transcription) {
        if (p.test(cons)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public int countPhonotype(Consonant.Place place) {
    return countPhonotypeBy(cons -> cons.getPlace().equals(place));
}

public int countPhonotype(Consonant.Manner manner) {
    return countPhonotypeBy(cons -> cons.getManner().equals(manner));
}
```

Но можно пойти дальше и использовать для подсчета стримы.

```java
private int countPhonotypeBy(Predicate<Consonant> p) {
    return (int) Arrays.stream(this.transcription).filter(p).count();
}
```

Это если `transcription` - массив, у коллекций есть собственный метод `stream`

```java
private int countPhonotypeBy(Predicate<Consonant> p) {
    return (int) this.transcription.stream().filter(p).count();
}
```

Comment: @Алексей есть еще синтаксис покороче, о котором вам написали в комментарии к вопросу

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если речь о `Class::method`, то я не вижу возможности сократить что-то в этом примере таким образом. Хотя не исключено, что я упускаю очевидное.